# How To Write A Simple Click Opacity Fade?

Tags: jquery, web

Okay, so I'm simply trying to make the opacity fade from 0 to 1 and then 1 to 0 on click. I'm assuming that I need to write an if statement. Here is the code as it is right now.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#soilink').click(function() {$('#soi').animate({opacity:1}, 400 );}

    );
```

So right now, if I click on the link on my website, the div area called #soi fades in. However, the second part is that I need to be able to click the link once again so it fades back to 0. Haven't quite figured that part out.

**EDIT**

I want this to toggle, however using the toggle function will result in the div completely becoming absent from the html, causing other divs to shift.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [fadeTo()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeto/) function for that

```
$('#soilink').click(function() {
   $('#soi').fadeTo(400, 1);
});
```

If you are trying create a toggle effect, there is also a [fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) function.

```
$('#soilink').click(function() {
   $('#soi').fadeToggle(400);
});
```

Update:

Here is how to do that.

```
$('#soilink').click(function() {
   $('#soi').stop().fadeTo(400, $('#soi').css('opacity') == 0 ? 1 : 0); 
});
```

Comment: Okay, well I did the toggle function first. But when the div is hidden, the other divs collapse and I need the structure of the site to maintain. So I found that opacity fading was good because the div would always hold it's place.

Comment: @user2122160, On that case, create a fixed container outside `#soi` and keep `#soi` inside. Thus keeping the structure intact after fading.

Comment: okay, the structure is still falling out of sync even with a div in place. you want me to fix it using css right?

Comment: @user2122160, Yes give it the width of height of the `#soi`

Comment: when i fixed it it displaced. by the way, i should mention i'm using skeleton grid system to keep things organized. so when i use the div class of the same columns as #soi then i think that would specify.

Comment: is there a way to write an if statement for click opacity levels? cause the opacity 0 to 1 thing was the best solution i had, i'm sure writing the if statement to be able to click it to disappear would solve it

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#soilink').click(function() {
   $('#soi').fadeToggle();
});
```

Here is an example how to create custom toggles if you'll ever need it:

```
var values=['v1', 'v2'],
    c=0;  // Set to "1" if you have your element initially hidden (display:none;)
$('#element').click(function() {
   console.log( values[c++%2]) ); // v2 // v1 // v2 // v1 // v2 .....
});
```

<kbd>**[CUSTOM EXAMPLE - LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ufoxoh/1/edit)**</kbd>

Comment: this worked actually, it maintained the form of the page. is there any way i can have the #soi div be hidden first? i tried having the opacity start at 0, but you have to click the link twice for the script to work. maybe that's something i need to deal with??

Comment: @user2122160 actually it's very simple, let's say you have in your CSS: `#soi{display:none;}` than just set the "counter" value to `1` instead to `0` http://jsbin.com/ufoxoh/4/edit

Answer (score 0):

Create a visible class for `#soi` that has the desired full opacity. Then toggle that on click of the link.

```
$('#soilink').click(function() {
    $('#soi').toggleClass('visible', 400);
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hb6yq/)**

Note that this requires [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/toggleClass/).